# Is it possible to make a functor in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, functor

I'm trying to make a function that holds state but is called with foo().
Is it possible?

Comment: Joel Spolsky has a really nice article on javascript functors: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/08/01.html

Comment: This article is not on functors, it's on functions.

Comment: @torazaburo There are no functors in Javascript. But the same C++ feature can be emulated using functions because they are objects.

Comment: I wrote an article about [Functors in dynamically typed languages like Javascript](https://medium.com/@iquardt/functors-in-a-dynamically-typed-language-like-javascript-ed2c8889db#.l3a5w622p)

Comment: ... This isn't asking about a functor. This is asking about closures

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
var foo = (function () {
    var state = 0;

    return function () {
        return state++;
    };
})();
```

Or, following [the Wikipedia example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object):

```
var makeAccumulator = function (n) {
    return function (x) {
        n += x;
        return n;
    };
};

var acc = makeAccumulator(2);

alert(acc(2)); // 4
alert(acc(3)); // 7
```

JavaScript is one of those languages that has, IMHO, excellent support for functions as first class citizens.

Comment: Which "it". The foo() example does indeed return undefined. It was just as an example. The accumulator example should work as expected. I've added a simple use case.

Comment: Thanks. The foo example. I commented before the second example.

Comment: The foo example didn't return a value.  I've added a return so that it should behave as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Since Javascript functions are first-class objects, this is the way to do it:

```
var state = 0;
var myFunctor = function() { alert('I functored: ' + state++);};
```

The `state` variable will be available to the `myFunctor` function in its local closure. (Global in this example). The other answers to this question have the more sophisticated examples.

There's no equivalent to just "implementing operator ()" on some existing object, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can treat functions as objects and give them "member variables". Here we're using an internal function in `fact`, but instead of just declaring it as a local variable (`var loop = ...`), we're putting its definition outside of the function, using object syntax (`fact.loop = ...`). This lets us essentially "export" the internal `loop` function of `fact` so that it can be reused by the function `doubleFact`.

```
var fact = function(n) {
  return fact.loop(n, 1);
};

fact.loop = function(n, acc) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return acc;
  } else {
    return fact.loop(n-1, acc * n);
  }
};

var doubleFact = function(x) {
  return fact.loop(x * 2, 1);
};

console.log(fact(5)); // 120
console.log(doubleFact(5)); // 3628800
```

The same idea could be used to maintain state.

```
var countCalled = function() {
  console.log("I've been called " + (++countCalled.callCount) + " times.");
};

countCalled.callCount = 0;

countCalled(); // I've been called 1 times.
countCalled(); // I've been called 2 times.
countCalled(); // I've been called 3 times.
```

If you want to be able to instantiate multiple ones, each with their own state, try this:

```
var CallCounter = function(name) {
  var f = function() {
    console.log(name + " has been called " + (++f.callCount) + " times.");
  };
  f.callCount = 0;
  return f;
};

var foo = CallCounter("foo");
var bar = CallCounter("bar");

foo();
foo();
bar();
foo();
bar();
bar();
bar();

console.log(foo.callCount);
console.log(bar.callCount);
```

Outputs:

```
foo has been called 1 times.
foo has been called 2 times.
bar has been called 1 times.
foo has been called 3 times.
bar has been called 2 times.
bar has been called 3 times.
bar has been called 4 times.
3
4
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use closure returning function with attached function object properties.
Parameters of such functor (closure) could be changed after initialization,
which can be useful when building some computation that can be run/configured later. Take a look at example below. This answer is similar to limp_chimp .

```js
function functor() {

  var run = function runX() {

    return runX.functorParam;

    // or: 

    // return run.functorParam;
  };

  run.functorParam = 'functor param'; // default value

  return run;
}

var f1 = functor();

// call f1
f1(); // 'functor param'


// lets change functor parameters:
f1.functorParam = 'Hello';


// call f1
f1(); // 'Hello'
```